# Error while Invoking AS400 RPG From Java

Tags: java, ibm-midrange, rpg

With respect to my yesterday's [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104859/invoking-aso400-rpg-from-java) on invoking RPG program using Java, the below exception is through from RPG Program.

****Application error.  RNX9001 unmonitored by ZM30000R at statement *N, instruction X'0000**'.**

I have used the code that was posted in that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104859/invoking-aso400-rpg-from-java) and after changing by the suggestions that were given in answers.

Any idea of what could be the reason for this error?

Comment: Nice to see that Big Blue's error messages are as helpful as ever. :]

Comment: Well, IBM offers you a free game for your working hours. You must combine several messages from several places to get the complete picture. Sound like a famous child's play, doesn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log on to the iSeries, and study the program dump. That dump should show the reason that the program stopped with this error. If you can not log on, then you will not solve this issue.

More information is in the [IBM Infocenter](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp) or the [RPG manual](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/topic/books/sc092508.pdf) .

Comment: Many Thanks Robert,the dumps has revealed that the Numeric parameter is Packed decimal. Thanks for you suggestions