# Call RPG function from Java

Tags: java, rpg, jtopen

I want to find away to call a RPG Function from Java.  I must be able to pass in parameters and to return result sets, and output parameters.

I was able to find [this](http://search400.techtarget.com/answer/How-to-call-an-RPG-program-from-Java) but it is using a stored procedure. Not the way I want to go.
I also found this question [Invoking AS400 RPG From Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104859/invoking-as400-rpg-from-java) they talking about [JTOpen](http://jt400.sourceforge.net/). Still trying to look for tutorials to see if JTOpen could help me, but have not found any yet.

If you can please help me to find a way to call RPG functions from Java, I would appreciated that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is explained in the IBM Toolbox for Java (JTOpen) [Programmer's Guide](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzahh/page1.htm).

Specifically the [ProgramCall class](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzahh/pgmc.htm) will allow you to call an HLL from Java.

Comment: Funny enough I found this link, but for some reason it would not load the page, but it seems to be working now. Will have a look, thanks.

Comment: Yes this is what I was looking for, I am having a few issues with the testing code, but I'll ask that in another question.

Answer (score 1):

From V5R2 version there is IBM Toolbox for Java (JTOpen is Open Source Version but  you can find all jars needed in /QIBM/ProdJava/OS400/jt400/lib jt400.jar and jt400native.jar).
Look at this link
http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/07/call-rpgle-from-java-using-package.html
there's a good example for calling an rpg object from java passing parameters ...

Bye
Depe