# Java ProgramCall.run hangs

Tags: java, rpg, jtopen

Busy trying to [Call RPG function from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16693448/call-rpg-function-from-java/16693560) and got [this](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzahh/pgmc.htm) example from [JamesA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/58061/jamesa). But now I am having trouble, here is my code:

```
AS400 system = new AS400("MachineName");
ProgramCall program = new ProgramCall(system);    
    try
    {
        // Initialise the name of the program to run.
        String programName = "/QSYS.LIB/LIBNAME.LIB/FUNNAME.PGM";
        // Set up the 3 parameters.
        ProgramParameter[] parameterList = new ProgramParameter[2];
        // First parameter is to input a name.
        AS400Text OperationsItemId = new AS400Text(20);
        parameterList[0] = new ProgramParameter(OperationsItemId.toBytes("TestID"));
        AS400Text CaseMarkingValue = new AS400Text(20);
        parameterList[1] = new ProgramParameter(CaseMarkingValue.toBytes("TestData"));

        // Set the program name and parameter list.         
        program.setProgram(programName, parameterList);
        // Run the program.
        if (program.run() != true)
        {
            // Report failure.
            System.out.println("Program failed!");
            // Show the messages.
            AS400Message[] messagelist = program.getMessageList();
            for (int i = 0; i < messagelist.length; ++i)
            {
                // Show each message.
                System.out.println(messagelist[i]);
            }
        }
        // Else no error, get output data.
        else
        {
            AS400Text text = new AS400Text(50);
            System.out.println(text.toObject(parameterList[1].getOutputData()));
            System.out.println(text.toObject(parameterList[2].getOutputData()));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //System.out.println("Program " + program.getProgram() + " issued an exception!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Done with the system.
    system.disconnectAllServices();
```

The application Hangs at this line`if (program.run() != true)`, and I wait for about 10 minutes and then I terminate the application.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

**Edit**
Here is the message on the job log:

> Client request - run program QSYS/QWCRTVCA.
>   Client request - run program LIBNAME/FUNNAME.
>   File P6CASEL2 in library *LIBL not found or inline data file missing.
>   Error message CPF4101 appeared during OPEN.
>   Cannot resolve to object YOBPSSR. Type and Subtype X'0201' Authority

FUNNAME insert a row into table P6CASEPF through a view called P6CASEL2. P6CASEL2 is in a different library lets say LIBNAME2. Is there away to maybe set the JobDescription?

Comment: in my case in hang on `return new AS400Text(length, client).toBytes(ifNullBlank(value));` even before calling anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I saw that my problem is that my library list is not setup, and for some reason, the user we are using, does not have a Job Description. So to over come this I added the following code before calling the `program.run()`

```
CommandCall command = new CommandCall(system);
command.run("ADDLIBLE LIB(LIBNAME)");
command.run("ADDLIBLE LIB(LIBNAME2)");
```

This simply add this LIBNAME, and LIBNAME2 to the user's library list.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure `FUNNAME.PGM` is terminating and not hung with a MSGW?  Check `QSYSOPR` for any messages.

---

[Class ProgramCall](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzahh%2Fpgmc.htm):

> NOTE: When the program runs within the host server job, the library list will be the initial library list specified in the job description in the user profile.

Comment: Looked at the job logs, an updated my question with the error message I found.

Answer (score 1):

Oh yes, the problem is Library list not set ... take a look at this discussion on Midrange.com, there are different work-around ...
http://archive.midrange.com/java400-l/200909/msg00032.html

...
Depe