# How to run a java program on ibmi server

Tags: java, ibm-midrange

Is it possible to call a java pgm that is hosted on my ibmi from the pc?
I want to create a java program on my pc. The program should create a connection to my ibmi and call a java program hosted on my machine.

After searching in the web i try to find a solution in this forum.
is that possible?
what are the preferences that make that ?

**edit**
the java program on my ibmi should call a rpg/cobol program to grab some data and return them to the calling java on my pc.

bye jogi

Comment: what is the solution you found, have you tried that (or something else) yet ?

Comment: i didnt find a solution so i asked in this forum.

Comment: There are multiple possibilities. A basic description of what the java pgm would do would help pick a direction.

Comment: ok, i changed my post. at first, the program on my ibmi should call exisiting RPG programs that grab data for statistics and return the data to the calling programm...

Comment: Can you clarify if you want to **write** java to run on IBM i and that you then will call it from your PC? Should we assume that you're a java developer? An example possibility is a java stored procedure. That'd be accessible from a PC.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the [JT400](http://jt400.sourceforge.net/) project...

The IBM Toolbox for Java is a library of Java classes supporting the client/server and internet programming models to a system running IBM i (or i5/OS or OS/400). The classes can be used by Java applets, servlets, and applications to easily access IBM i data and resources.

Answer (score 2):

[Charles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2933177/charles) is right. JT400 is the way to go.

[Here](http://www.mcpressonline.com/networking/general/pc-commands-from-the-as400.html) is a functional example.

Please provide some feedback if you run in trouble.

Comment: JT400 looks very nice. i tested commandcalls and that worked fine. Is it also possible to call a java server-program on my ibmi from the pc ?

Comment: @user2976312, yes.  There is a "Run Java Program" command.  Under the "native" naming, this command is RUNJVA.  However, IBM include an alias command simply named JAVA.

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest looking at the answer to the following Stack Overflow post?

[Accessing RPG on iSeries from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184864/accessing-rpg-on-iseries-from-java)

Depending on the situation, it might make more sense to call the RPG program directly from your PC's Java program.  Otherwise, execute the CL Java command:
JAVA CLASS(my.java.class) PARM('a' 'b' 'c') CLASSPATH('/path/to/jarFile.jar') using the CommandCall class as described in the above mentioned post.