# JAVA GUI and AS400 RPGLE

Tags: java, user-interface, ibm-midrange, rpgle

I know how to code in JAVA and also RPGLE.  The problem I am having is connecting the two.  I want to be able to use a JAVA GUI as input and pass the parms as values to an RPGLE module that then saves these to a file.  Like I had stated I know how to do the process separatly, but I am having problems figuring out how to pass from ECLIPSE to the iSeries.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you have access to write to the db on your AS400?

Comment: Yes i do have access to that

Comment: Why not just write it directly there w/Java? Maybe I'm not understanding what you're trying to do, but I would think you'd write directly to the db using the java app to do what the module does...

Comment: That would also be fine too, but we already have modules with logic for calculations already written. I don't want redundant code.

Comment: The JAVA GUI would pass values to RPGLE, calculations would take place, then this would write to the database file

Comment: I suggest looking at these SO questions for some help/samples:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104859/invoking-as400-rpg-from-java/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184864/accessing-rpg-on-iseries-from-java/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't "pass values to an RPGLE module"

*MODULE objects are non-executable.  They must be bound into either a a *PGM object or a *SRVPGM object in order for the procedures contained in them to be executed.

It'd be helpful if your question included the code you've tried.

I assume you're using [JTOpen](http://jt400.sourceforge.net/index.html), "a library of Java classes supporting the client/server and internet programming models to a system running IBM i."

That being the case, you have two direct options..

- [ProgramCall class](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzahh/pgmc.htm)
- [JDBC CallableStatement interface](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzahh/jdbccst.htm)

Comment: That is very helpful thank you! Yes I am using JTOpen.  The two options you linked answers my question.

Comment: If you could do me a solid please go to IBM and flame JTOPEN about not being setup for MAVEN because its too much work.

Comment: @danny117 Why would anyone want to `flame' the JTOpen project for not including certain features? That suggests a serious misunderstanding of a couple major points of "open source", i.e., (1) it's "open source" and (2) it's developed mostly by others for you to use for free.

Comment: We flame IBM on JTOPEN Because we are in.jar hell having to take the time to manage the correct  jar files are downloaded and in place when maven could be doing that automatically.

Comment: @danny117, have you looked here? https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jt400/jt400 or here? https://maven-repository.com/artifact/net.sf.jt400/jt400  Both have the latest 9.1 version...

Comment: iOfcourse maven pulls that in like magic but jt400 is not the latest release of jtopen.

Comment: @danny117,  jtopen is the current name for what used to be called jt400.  But the .JAR itself is still called jt400.  The links I provides both have the latest version 9.1

Comment: When IBM promotes the JTopen maven on their website then I'll be satisified.